# Find all roots of $z^2=3-4i$.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all roots of $z^2=3-4i$.

$z^2=3-4i$

$z^2+4i-3=0$

But how do I go on from here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way people will *really* solve it.

If we have a root $z_0$, then $-z_0$ is also a root. Since this is a quadratic, there can't be more than $2$ roots, so we just need to guess one root $z_0$. How do we do that?

Observe that $|z^2| = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$, therefore $|z|=\sqrt{5}$. Now, the only nice numbers with that absolute value are $\pm 1 \pm 2i$ and $\pm 2 \pm i$. Geometric intuition says that one of the roots must be found in the 4th quadrant. A quick check shows that indeed $z_0 = 2-i$ fits the bill:
$$
(2-i)^2 = 4 - 4i + i^2 = 3 - 4i.
$$

So the answer is $2-i$ and $-2 + i$.

This is how a lazy person like me solves a problem like this. It is perfectly legitimate to guess the answer (if you have a good argument why other answers are impossible, which in this case follows from the general knowledge that a quadratic has at most two roots). Only when guessing doesn't work right away do people start testing more powerful general approaches.

Comment: Hm, I'd really like to see the reasons for downvotes. Although be careful, I am this close to another rant on how smart guessing is the way things are actually done in mathematics.

Comment: Same happened to my answer. Quite puzzling...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Write $3 - 4i$ in polar form,

$$3 - 4i = r e^{i\theta}$$

for an appropriate positive $r$ and $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$. Then use the fact that the two square roots of $re^{i\theta}$ are

$$\pm \sqrt{r} e^{i\theta/2}$$

Comment: Are you sure about the $\pm$? This is usually taken into account by the fact that $r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\theta+2\pi n)}$ where $n$ is a whole number.

Comment: @FlybyNight Yes, they'll give equivalent answers precisely due to the fact that $-e^{i\pi} = 1$. I didn't give the general method here since the question is only about square roots, and I don't think that the general method clarifies the solution in this case.

Comment: IMHO, this answer is potentially misleading. The OP is quite likely to assume that the solution to $z^3 = 3-4\mathrm{i}$ is $\sqrt[3]{r}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta/3}$ alone. This is a standard problem that asks for consideration modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: Well the OP can consider $(se^{i\psi})^3 = re^{i\theta}$ so that $s = r^{\fract{1}{3}$ and $\phi = \fract{\theta}{3} + \fract{2pi*k}{3}$

Comment: Sorry it should say $s = r^{\fract{1}{3}}$

Answer (score 3):

Denesting $\,\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{n}}\,$ can be done by a simple rule that I discovered in my youth.

**Simple Denesting Rule** $\rm\ \ \, \color{blue}{subtract\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\:,\ \ then\ \  \color{brown}{divide\ out}\ \sqrt{trace} $

Recall $\rm\: w = a + b\sqrt{n}\: $ has **norm** $\rm =\: w\:\cdot\: w' = (a + b\sqrt{n})\ \cdot\: (a - b\sqrt{n})\ =\: a^2 - n\: b^2 $

and, furthermore,  $\rm\:w\:$ has **trace** $\rm\: =\: w+w' =  (a + b\sqrt{n}) + (a - b\sqrt{n})\: =\:  2\:a$

---

Here $\:3-4i\:$ has norm $= 25.\:$ $\rm\ \color{blue}{subtracting\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\ = -5\ $ yields $\ \  8-4i\:$

which has $\rm\ \sqrt{trace}\: =\: \sqrt{16}\ =\ 4.\ \ \ \color{brown}{Dividing\ it\ out}\ $ yields $\ \ (8-4i)/4\, =\, 2-i$

---

Or:  $\:3-4i\:$ has norm $= 25.\:$ $\rm\ \color{blue}{subtracting\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\ \ = \ 5\ \ $ yields $\  {-}2-4i\:$

which has $\rm\ \sqrt{trace}\: =\: \sqrt{-4} = 2i.\ \ \color{brown}{Dividing\ it\ out}\ $ yields $\ (-2-4i)/(2i)\, =\, i-2$

---

One may choose the sign of the square-root so that the arithmetic is simpler, as in the first case above. For many further worked examples see my [prior posts on denesting.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denesting+subtract+norm+trace)

Comment: The guy who gave a downvote simply didn't get it. +1

Answer (score 3):

Solve: $z^2 = 3 - 4i$

Let
$$z= x + yi$$
Rewrite as
$$(x + yi)^2 = 3 - 4i$$
Expand
$$x^2 +2xyi + y^2i^2 = 3 - 4i$$
Simplify
$$x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi = 3 - 4i$$
real/imaginary parts
$$x^2 - y^2 = 3$$

and

$$2xy = -4$$
$$xy = -2$$
Therefore $y = -\frac{2}{x}$.

Substitute $y = -\frac 2x$ into $x^2 - y^2 = 3$, giving
$$x^2 - \frac{4}{x^2} = 3$$
Multiply by $x^2$:
$x^4 - 4 = 3x^2$
Factor

$$x^4 - 3x^2 - 4 = 0$$
$$(x^2 + 1) (x^2 - 4) = 0$$
$$(x^2+ 1) (x + 2) (x - 2) = 0$$
Given $xy = -2$

for $x = 2$ then $y = -1$ therefore $z = 2 - i$

for $x = -2$ then $y = 1$ therefore $z = -2 + i$

Comment: Please use complete sentences and better formatting so that your answer is as clear and understandable as possible.

Comment: This answer is simply unreadable.  Recommending deletion.

Comment: Edited answer. Please check if formatting is correct

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $\displaystyle z=a+ib$

So, we have $\displaystyle a^2-b^2+2ab i=3-4i$

Equate the real & the imaginary parts

Use $(a^2+b^2)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2$ to find $a,b$

Observe that the signs of $a,b$ are opposite

Comment: I'm not sure where to go with the 3rd equation?

Comment: @MrCroutini, we have $a^2-b^2=3,2ab=-4,\implies a^2+b^2=\sqrt{3^2+(-4)^2}=+5$ Can you find $a^2,b^2$ form here?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm really not getting this.. :/

Comment: @MrCroutini, add $a^2+b^2=5, a^2-b^2=3\implies 2a^2=8\implies a^2=4\iff a=\pm2$  and we have $2ab=-4\iff b=-\frac2a$

Comment: Isn't $a^2-b^2=3^2-(-4)^2=-7$?

Comment: @lab This method can be packaged into a simple rule - see my answer. Happy denesting!